# Jackson JSON custom serialization for certain fields

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Is there a way using Jackson JSON Processor to do custom field level serialization? For example, I'd like to have the class

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public int favoriteNumber;
}
```

serialized to the follow JSON:

```
{ "name": "Joe", "age": 25, "favoriteNumber": "123" }
```

Note that age=25 is encoded as a **number** while favoriteNumber=123 is encoded as a **string**. Out of the box Jackson marshalls `int` to a number. In this case I want favoriteNumber to be encoded as a string.

Comment: I wrote a post about [How to Write a Custom Serializer with Jackson](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/01/custom-serializer-jackson/?utm_source=stack-overflow-ao&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=custom-serializer-jackson) that may be helpful to some.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can implement a custom serializer as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator

public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    @JsonSerialize(using = IntToStringSerializer.class, as=String.class)
    public int favoriteNumber:
}

 
public class IntToStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Integer> {
  
    @Override
    public void serialize(Integer tmpInt, 
                          JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, 
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) 
                          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(tmpInt.toString());
    }
}
```

Java should handle the autoboxing from `int` to `Integer` for you.

Comment: Jackson-databind (at least 2.1.3) already contains special ToStringSerializer, see my answer.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Can you help with my [deserializing problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725278/how-to-handle-localized-decimal-separator-with-jackson) please?

Comment: note `as=String.class` is ignored due to the `using` parameter, and is not required here. [*Note: if using() is also used it has precedence (since it directly specified serializer, whereas this would only be used to locate the serializer) and value of this annotation property is ignored.*](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html#as())

Comment: Is there any less terrible way to do this? Like `Person implements ToJson`?

Comment: @KevinBowersox There is probably a typo in the first words of the answer: you meant "serializer", not "deserializer" (though deserializer may also be of insterest).

Comment: In my case, it even failed on the `as=String.class` part, due to the types I used. @kevin-bowersox, I suggest updating your comment, in line with what @GarethLatty said.

Comment: @Bert I second that. I get a `Cannot read latest test results
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid definition for property "instant" (of type `com.MyType`): Cannot refine serialization type [simple type, class java.time.Instant] into java.lang.String; types not related` message, when I don't remove the `as`-annotation.

Comment: we were using custom serialization but now i can't use POJOs anymore as more clients will be accessing our rest service. how can i still custom serialize certain fields ? just posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332390/custom-serialization-based-on-attribute-in-json

Comment: In Kotlin, it's impossible to write "as = " since "as" is a reserved keyword. At least not without any hacks I haven't bothered to look up yet :)

Comment: In kotlin, you can use reserved keywords by surrounding them with backticks. @kit

Comment: This serializes for types and not fields. How do I serialize specific `fields`? Does this solution not also map `age` to a string or does it maintain it as an `int`?

Answer (score 72):

Jackson-databind (at least 2.1.3) provides special `ToStringSerializer` (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer`)

Example:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
    public int favoriteNumber:
}
```

Comment: What about the reverse where a String needs to be converted to an int? I don't see ToIntSerializer.class.

Comment: @jEremyB You might have to write a [custom deserializer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20638114/17339)

Comment: ToStringSerializer works but FloatSerializer brings this message: Could not write content: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

Answer (score 20):

In case you don't want to pollute your model with annotations and want to perform some custom operations, you could use mixins.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.setMixInAnnotation(Person.class, PersonMixin.class);
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

Override age:

```
public abstract class PersonMixin {
    @JsonSerialize(using = PersonAgeSerializer.class)
    public String age;
}
```

Do whatever you need with the age:

```
public class PersonAgeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Integer integer, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeString(String.valueOf(integer * 52) + " months");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

jackson-annotations provides `@JsonFormat` which can handle a lot of customizations without the need to write the custom serializer.

For example, requesting a `STRING` shape for a field with numeric type will output the numeric value as string

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    public int favoriteNumber;
}
```

will result in the desired output

```
{"name":"Joe","age":25,"favoriteNumber":"123"}
```

Answer (score 16):

Add a `@JsonProperty` annotated getter, which returns a `String`, for the `favoriteNumber` field:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    private int favoriteNumber;

    public Person(String name, int age, int favoriteNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.favoriteNumber = favoriteNumber;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getFavoriteNumber() {
        return String.valueOf(favoriteNumber);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Person p = new Person("Joe", 25, 123);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(p)); 
        // {"name":"Joe","age":25,"favoriteNumber":"123"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

with the help of **@JsonView** we can decide fields of model classes to serialize which satisfy the minimal criteria ( we have to define the criteria) like we can have one core class with 10 properties but only 5 properties can be serialize which are needful for client only

Define our Views by simply creating following class:

```
public class Views
{
    static class Android{};
    static class IOS{};
    static class Web{};
}
```

Annotated model class with views:

```
public class Demo 
{
    public Demo() 
    {
    }

@JsonView(Views.IOS.class)
private String iosField;

@JsonView(Views.Android.class)
private String androidField;

@JsonView(Views.Web.class)
private String webField;

 // getters/setters
...
..
}
```

Now we have to write custom json converter by simply extending HttpMessageConverter class from spring as:

```
    public class CustomJacksonConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<Object> 
    {
    public CustomJacksonConverter() 
        {
            super();
        //this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.ClientView.class));
        this.delegate.getObjectMapper().configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
        this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

    }

    // a real message converter that will respond to methods and do the actual work
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter delegate = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return delegate.canRead(clazz, mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return delegate.canWrite(clazz, mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return delegate.getSupportedMediaTypes();
    }

    @Override
    public Object read(Class<? extends Object> clazz,
            HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException,
            HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return delegate.read(clazz, inputMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Object obj, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException 
    {
        synchronized(this) 
        {
            String userAgent = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getHeader("userAgent");
            if ( userAgent != null ) 
            {
                switch (userAgent) 
                {
                case "IOS" :
                    this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.IOS.class));
                    break;
                case "Android" :
                    this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.Android.class));
                    break;
                case "Web" :
                    this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView( Views.Web.class));
                    break;
                default:
                    this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView( null ));
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // reset to default view
                this.delegate.getObjectMapper().setConfig(this.delegate.getObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().withView( null ));
            }
            delegate.write(obj, contentType, outputMessage);
        }
    }

}
```

Now there is need to tell spring to use this custom json convert by simply putting this in dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <bean id="jsonConverter" class="com.mactores.org.CustomJacksonConverter" >
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

That's how you will able to decide which fields to get serialize.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom serializer inline in the mixin. Then annotate a field with it. See example below that appends " *- something else* " to lang field. This is kind of ***hackish*** - if your serializer requires something like a repository or anything injected by spring, this is going to be a problem. Probably best to use a custom deserializer/serializer instead of a mixin.

```
package com.test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.test.Argument;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
//Serialize only fields explicitly mentioned by this mixin.
@JsonAutoDetect(
    fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE,
    setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE,
    getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE,
    isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE,
    creatorVisibility = Visibility.NONE
)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"lang", "name", "value"})
public abstract class V2ArgumentMixin {

  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;

  @JsonSerialize(using = LangCustomSerializer.class, as=String.class)
  @JsonProperty("lang")
  private String lang;

  @JsonProperty("value")
  private Object value;


  
  public static class LangCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value,
                          JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      jsonGenerator.writeObject(value.toString() + "  - something else");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up combining the two answers (and using the implementation provided by ToStringSerializer)

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12046979/474377
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14873731/474377

POJO:

```
public class MyPojo{
  LocalDate date;

  @JsonSerialize(using = CurrencySerializer.class)
  double amount;
}
```

Serializer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JacksonStdImpl;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializerBase;

@JacksonStdImpl
public class CurrencySerializer extends ToStringSerializerBase
{
  public final static CurrencySerializer instance = new CurrencySerializer();

  public CurrencySerializer() { super(Object.class); }


  public CurrencySerializer(Class<?> handledType) {
    super(handledType);
  }

  @Override
  public final String valueToString(Object value) {
    return "$ " + value.toString();
  }
}
```