# How to JsonFormat long value with commas

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-modules

I have a front-end I created that allows for a numeric value.  Of course, the value the user should enter should strictly be a numeric value.  That is no decimal, no commas, no $, no other values, and I can control this on the UI if I need to.

However, in the case the user does enter free text in this numeric box, I am looking for an easy way to convert  123,456  to just 123456.

I am using Spring 5, Spring MVC, and the REST Controller works fine if I am passing into it '123456', however, because the POJO has a long value, I am wondering if I can with Jackson FasterXML use @JsonFormat annotation to take 123,456 and convert that to 123456????

Let's say someone enters in 123,456,789.00 as a value, and we know this can be converted to a long, so I wonder if we could use the @JSonFormat annotation on this field to make it convert to 123456789???

Is there something I could do in the setter of the POJO to make this work?

I suppose I could also just change my POJO to accept a String value, and then remove all commas, all decimals, remove $, remove any other non numeric values, and then would be the catch-all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid to tell you, but there is no way to achieve this with `@JsonFormat`.

Two possible approaches are described in the first two answers of the question [How to deserialize a float value with a localized decimal separator with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725278/how-to-deserialize-a-float-value-with-a-localized-decimal-separator-with-jackson), as they are:

- Implementing a custom [JSON deserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) with the logic you described with your words: […]and then remove all commas[…]
- Using a localized [`DefaultDeserializationContext`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/DefaultDeserializationContext.java) which parses the number included in your strings depending on the given `Locale`

Comment: Yep.  This answer led to my fix.  Exactly as you described!