# convert CSV file to json with comma decimal delimiter jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, csvtojson

I have the following csv file

> ```
> id;productCode;cost
> 123132;10204;524,07 
> 123132;10205;222,02
> ```

I am looking for suggestions on how to handle a csv file that have a comma in  value (eg cost).

I am using following code:

**Class ResultFile**

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class ResultFile {

    private String id;
    private String productCode;
    private double cost;   
}
```

**Controller**

```
File temporaryFile = new File("input.csv");
CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader().withColumnSeparator(';').withoutQuoteChar();
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
csvMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
List<Object> data = csvMapper.readerFor(ResultFile.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(temporaryFile).readAll();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String st = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
System.out.println(mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(data));
return st;
```

**The error**

> E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E:
>   [Servlet Error]-[DispatcherServlet]:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot
>   deserialize value of type `double` from String "524,07": not a valid
>   Double value
>        at [Source: (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader); line: 2,
>   column: 14] (through reference chain:
>   com.ibm.gr.melissa.beans.ResultFile["cost"])
>         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:67)
>         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1679)
>         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext.java:935)
>         at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$DoubleDeserializer._parseDouble(NumberDeserializer

Comment: That CSV format is not valid JSON format, so you will need to provide a custom deserializer. See similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725278/how-to-deserialize-a-float-value-with-a-localized-decimal-separator-with-jackson

Comment: @Pieterjan Deconinck You are right