# Individual Serializer in Springframework

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization

I use springframeworks in my project and for JSON we use `jackson`. One list should be serialized in a specific way, i.e. should have a specific JSON-output. I followed the answers of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046786/jackson-json-custom-serialization-for-certain-fields) but this fails.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = UserDataSerializer.class)
List<TestObj> lstTest;
```

and

```
public class UserDataSerializer extends StdSerializer<TestObj> {

    protected UserDataSerializer(Class<TestObj> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(TestObj value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField(value.getName(), value.getValue());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

but unfortunately this approach fails with an exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [test3backend] in context with path [/test] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.f
actory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'me.test.entities.UserDataSerializer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor paramete
r 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<me.test.entities.TestObj>' av
ailable: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<at.me.test.entities.TestObj>' available: expected at leas
t 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Any hints how to properly configure it in my project?

Comment: have you annotated your class `UserDataSerializer ` with `@bean` annotation

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with this issue was that I did not include a default null constructor, i.e. adding

```
public UserDataSerializer() {
    this(null);
}
```

solved this issue.