# Custom serialization based on attribute in json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I get some json as input to rest service. 
part of json is as below

```
"attachment":[  
         {  
            "name":"bigimage1.jpg",
            "id":1,
            "contentType":"image/jpeg",
            "data":"very_big_base64encodedimage"
         },
         {  
            "name":"bigimage2.jpg",
            "contentType":"image/gif",
            "data":"very_big_base64encodedimage"
         },
```

I am supposed to copy value of "data" to s3 and rest to a queue. Currently I am using a customer serializer as annotation on the field like below. Rest of json is stored in queue.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
@JsonProperty("data")
private String data;
```

But as more applications will be accessing rest service in future, I can't use POJOs anymore and need to use generic object like ObjectNode. Applications agreed (to make it easier) to add an attribute like "contentType" to attachments to indicate that it is image.

```
        ObjectNode rootNode = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(inputJson);
```

how can I get around this problem. I need to somehow get custom serialization for "data" to store it to s3.

Comment: what is s3, you mean string?, and you want to get data manually from `ObjectNode`?

Comment: amazon s3. just some file storage. queues can't hold data in gb..or they don't want it.

Comment: i'm sorry i don't know how you get images as value in JSON